Can't build android unity apk && aab
I'm new to unity and I have to build apk and aab files of existing project
But when I try to build I get an error and I can't understand what's wrong

here is console logs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.1-6197926-osx Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

